# Анимация. Как лучше рисовать объекты с помощью css или canvas(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как лучше нарисовать объекты чтобы создать анимацию? Сначала мы поместили груз на правый контейнер, затем нажали кнопку старт и произошло перемещение контейнеров. Код нужно написать с помощью jQuery.
[image: начальная установка][image: конечная установка]

Comment: Может вам лучше использовать софт заточенный под рисование анимаций? Все перечисленные ниже библиотеки на относительно сложных анимациях типа вашей сдуются, это будет подъем солнца вручную. Типа аниматрона например.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте рисовал объекты в SVG, анимацию с помощью css, если анимация будет усложняться, можно использовать библиотеку http://snapsvg.io или http://d3js.org или чего легче http://svgjs.com. Если только jQuery то тогда jQuery с первым плагином который гуглится http://keith-wood.name/svg.html